# What is the most efficient data structure to store time series of partially changing array?

Tags: data-structures, core-data, time, time-series, series

My problem is I have an array of objects of size N. after every time (t+1), some of the values of the array may or may not change. so lets say t+1 index 15 changes but everything else stays the same.

What is the most efficient way to store something like this (in memory ) apart from just having an array of arrays of course? I want to be able to get all the values of the array for any time, say getValues(long time) in the most efficient way possible.

Say for 4 arrays

time 1
null
null
null
xyz

time 2
null
null
abc
xyz

(note that only abc changed here) but we still keep the values of the last index from time 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are asking for is known in the academic CS field as "partially persistent arrays". For more information about persistence, see [the survey of Kaplan](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~haimk/papers/persistent-survey.ps).

One simple solution is to use search trees instead of arrays. You can use purely functional balanced search trees to guarantee that each read or write takes O(lg n) worst-case time (where n is the size of the array), instead of O(1) time. (If you keep the time-stamped versions in an extendible array, adding a new version is O(1) amortized and accessing an old version is O(1) worst-case.)

If you are not familiar with purely functional search trees, you might read [this introduction to Clojure's persistent arrays](http://blog.higher-order.net/2010/08/16/assoc-and-clojures-persistenthashmap-part-ii/). They are purely functional trees indexed fixed-width integers (in the form of a trie), and thus have fixed depth. This might be the fastest solution to your problem, both worst-case and real-world.

The only other partially persistent arrays that I am aware of may take longer in the worst case. Some have better amortized complexity and some have better expected complexity if arrays are accessed in various restricted ways.